# How to say 'For a [period of time]'

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, idiom

How would I say that something won't end for a period of time, for example:

> Dinner isn't over for another hour.

I considered *Cena non finet ante hora*, but that didn't quite sound right.

#### Update:

I'm looking for a use that emphasizes the length of time, or how far away the end of the time period is, as in

> Ugh, dinner isn't over for another *two hours*!

or

> Yay!   The party is still going for two more hours!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would use the simple accusative here, as duration is one of its key uses. For a full explanation, see Gildersleeve and Lodge § 336. *Cenabimus  alteram horam.* "We will dine for another hour."

If you wanted to emphasize the ending point, i.e. "Dinner will be over in one hour," then you could use the ablative (G&L § 393). *Cenae finis una hora.* "Dinner's end is in one hour."

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to use the ablative (or the accusative) to emphasize not so much the endpoint, but how far away the endpoint is (see my update)?

Comment: @jpyams The ablative gives emphasis to the endpoint, so I recommend the accusative.

Comment: This is a special use of the accusative of extent, also used for distance: e.g., *we walked two miles.*

Comment: Is there a way to use this more as a negative? _Cenabimus alteram horam_ sounds rather neutral; would _Cena non finet alteram horam_ make sense in Latin?

Comment: @jpyams The verb (which would be *finiet*) is usually transitive, though it can be intransitive in late poetry. I would recommend *manere*, "to remain." *Cena alteram horam manebit."